# How to display some text before a value from a Dash callback?

Tags: python, html, dashboard, plotly-dash

Using Plotly Dash, I have line `html.H6(id='output_div')` that displays an integer (say 10).

I would like to display some text before that integer (say "This is integer"). I can’t use `{}.format()` in the callback function because I need to input that integer in another callback function.

How could I modify `html.H6(id='output_div')` to display "This is integer 10" on a single line instead of "10"?

Comment: Simple, you store it in a variable and print that variable and then later pass that variable to the callback function (if I understood you correctly?)

Comment: Well, the variable is stored as 'output_div' in Dash. But I'm not sure it is possible to print it without using Dash. Hence the question is about how to print it as required with Dash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [html.Span](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-html-components/span) is one way.

Your layout would contain:

```py
html.H6(
    id='output-1',
    children=[
        'This is integer ',
        html.Span(id='output-2', children=''),
    ]
)
```

And your callback out output the integer only to `'output-2'`. You could then use the `children` of `'output-2'` as an `Input` elsewhere to read that integer back into a callback. You could also update the `'output-1'` `children` prop if you need to change that to say something like `"This is a float"` or `"This is a string"`.